# Xamarin Android DatePicker visual bug on Min-Max Date

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

On Xamarin Android I have a DatePicker which is on spinner mode.I want to set min-max date for this DatePicker. I succeeded with this part. The problem is when we use month spinner to go to min-max date we get the visual bug on the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzkPd.png) which is "01" at the below. It doesn't effect functionality but looks bad for the user. I'm putting the code to the below so I would be very happy for any help.

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:overScrollMode="always"/>

var datePicker = root.FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.date_picker);
datePicker.MinDate = (long)(DateTime.Today - DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
datePicker.MaxDate = (long)(DateTime.Today.AddDays(30) - DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: To get last day of month use the next month fir day an subtract one day.  Adding 30 days is probably causing issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But the purpose of the DatePicker is to select a date 30days from now on not just last day of the month. It can be 07/04-07/05 for example.

Comment: The current date is between  max and min date when in spinner mode.